# morse to text dictionary - System.ArgumentException: An item with the same key has already been added

Tags: c#

Am creating program to translate morse code to text and text to morse code. First it worked fine with basic characeters in dictionary: abcdefghijklmnoprstuvzy0123456789 .Than i want to upgrade it to translate special characters in my language like ščťžýáíéôä?!:;.-_() .Problem is when i write it to my dictionary and give every char key it throws me excpetion : System.ArgumentException: An item with the same key has already been added.

This is my reading dictionary code

```
private void ReadDictionary(string filename)

     {
      string cesta = Path.GetDirectoryName(Process.GetCurrentProcess().MainModule.FileName);
        try {
           string[] lines = File.ReadAllLines(filename);
        if (lines != null) {

        }
                   foreach (string line in lines)
                {
                    string[] znaky = line.Split('=');
                    string key = znaky[0];
                    string value = znaky[1];
                    this.morzeovka.Add(key, value);
                    this.latinka.Add(value, key);
                }   
            }
          catch (IOException) {
             MessageBox.Show("Nepodarilo sa nacitat slovnik"+ Environment.NewLine + "Skontrolujete umiestnenie slovníka v:  "+cesta,"Chyba",MessageBoxButtons.OK,MessageBoxIcon.Error);
             System.Environment.Exit(1);
         }      
    }
}
```

This is my dictionary

```
a=.-
b=-...
c=-.-.
d=-..
e=.
f=..-.
g=--.
h=....
i=..
j=.---
k=-.-
l=.-..
m=--
n=-.
o=---
p=.--.
q=--.-
r=.-.
s=...
t=-
u=..-
v=...-
w=.--
x=-..-
y=-.--
z=--..
1=.----
2=..---
3=...--
4=....-
5=.....
6=-....
7=--...
8=---..
9=----.
0=-----
.=.-.-.-
,=--..--
?=..--..
!=--..-
;=-.-.-.
:=---...
(=--...
)=-.--.-
""=.-..-.
-=-....-
_=..--.-
@=.--.-.
+=.-.-.
/=-..-.
'=.----.
á=.--.-
ä=.-.-
é=..-..
ö=---.
ü=..--
ň=--.--
```

This is the full exception

```
System.ArgumentException: An item with the same key has already been added.
   at System.ThrowHelper.ThrowArgumentException(ExceptionResource resource)
   at System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2.Insert(TKey key, TValue value, Boolean add)
   at System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2.Add(TKey key, TValue value)
```

Thank you for any help,

PS: if i didnt post enought code, just ask what should i add

Comment: Well, what is the key in the iteration where the exception is thrown? Simply put a `try { ... } catch (ArgumentException) { System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(line); throw; }` around your `foreach` loop body.

Comment: Yes... why don't you use the debugger to establish the bad entries ? Your source data is bad, but we've already established that the data you have posted here is *not* a verbatim copy of your actual data. You're on your own really.

Comment: hmm sorrry but i dont undestand well (my english not that good). If i run debugg it show me this exceptions and line this.latinka.Add(value, key);  is yellow

Answer (score 1):

This item is causing the problem:

> ň=--.--

You should include a condition to validate if the key already exists in the dictionary before add it:

```
if (!morzeovka.ContainsKey(key))
{
    morzeovka.Add(key, value);
}
```

Comment: sorry, it was my bad, just mistake when i copy paste data here, in program i have only one value for every key, I edit my dictionary post, now its like i had it in real

Answer (score 1):

This works for me:

`7` & `(` have the same code `--...`

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var pairsEnum =
             pairs
            .Split(new string[] { Environment.NewLine }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)
            .Select(x => x.Split('='))
            .Select(x => new { Key = x[0].Trim(), Code = x[1].Trim() });

        var multipleKeys =
            pairsEnum
            .GroupBy(x => x.Key, (key, codes) => new { Key = key, Codes = codes })
            .Where(x => x.Codes.Count() > 1)
            .Select(x => new { Key = x.Key, Codes = x.Codes })
            .ToList();

        var multipleCodes =
          pairsEnum
           .GroupBy(x => x.Code, (code, keys) => new { Code = code, Keys = keys })
           .Where(x => x.Keys.Count() > 1)
           .Select(x => new { Keys = x.Keys, Code = x.Code})
           .ToList();

        var dic1 =
            pairsEnum
            .ToDictionary(x => x.Key, x => x.Code);

        // This will throw the same exception as in your example.
        var dic2 =
            pairsEnum
            .ToDictionary(x => x.Code, x => x.Key);
    }

    private static string pairs =
        @"
        a=.-
        b=-...
        c=-.-.
        d=-..
        e=.
        f=..-.
        g=--.
        h=....
        i=..
        j=.---
        k=-.-
        l=.-..
        m=--
        n=-.
        o=---
        p=.--.
        q=--.-
        r=.-.
        s=...
        t=-
        u=..-
        v=...-
        w=.--
        x=-..-
        y=-.--
        z=--..
        1=.----
        2=..---
        3=...--
        4=....-
        5=.....
        6=-....
        7=--...
        8=---..
        9=----.
        0=-----
        .=.-.-.-
        ,=--..--
        ?=..--..
        !=--..-
        ;=-.-.-.
        :=---...
        (=--...
        )=-.--.-
        """"=.-..-.
        -=-....-
        _=..--.-
        @=.--.-.
        +=.-.-.
        /=-..-.
        '=.----.
        á=.--.-
        ä=.-.-
        é=..-..
        ö=---.
        ü=..--
        ň=--.--";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To understand what's wrong with your source for dictionaries you can add simple checkings:

```
if (!morzeovka.ContainsKey(key))
{
    morzeovka.Add(key, value);
}
else
{
    Console.WriteLine("morzeovka duplicate: {0}", key);
}
if (!latinka.ContainsKey(value))
{
    latinka.Add(value, key);
}
else
{
    Console.WriteLine("latinka duplicate: {0}", value);
}
```

It will output to Console which duplicates dictionaries meet.

Comment: i manually catch what chars make problems, It is : áäéüö  . Still throw exceptions that there is already item with same value, but its not truth.

Comment: @JOLO, are you sure that your file has utf-8 encoding?